# .htaccess question - redirects after the domain name

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Apologies if this is answered elsewhere. I had a search for this on here, but I'm quite confused so I'm not 100% what to search for in the first place.

I have a Wordpress site which is at `exampledomain.com`. I also own `exampledomain.co.uk`, and I have put in the .htaccess file the follow lines:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^exampledomain.co.uk [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampledomain.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

These work fine in terms of changing `exampledomain.co.uk` to `exampledomain.com`, but the moment I add in something *after* the `exampledomain.co.uk` (i.e. `exampledomain.co.uk/page1`) the .htaccess file doesn't change it so it tries to load.

Is there something I can add to the .htaccess file which will sort this, so that, for example, if I were to type `exampledomain.co.uk/page1` it would redirect to `exampledomain.com/page1` ?

Thanks,

Charlie

<del>P.S. Apologise for the weirdly parsed example links, but as a new user it won't let me include more than two hyperlinks.</del>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format source code (either block or inline) with the `{}` toolbar button; that way, your examples won't count as hyperlink. I've done it for you this time. Also, please note that you can use the `example.com`, `example.net` and `example.org` domains in your examples, they are reserved for that precise purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do

```
RedirectPermanent / http://exampledomain.com
```

in the co.uk's config instead? mod_rewrite is very handy, but for a simple domain redirector, it's major overkill.

---

comment followup:

I'd go for something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} exampledomain.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://exampledomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The problem here is that the .co.uk is pointed at the same VPS (Plesk, Linux Ubuntu) as the .com, and the .com is set up on the Plesk to accept requests for the .co.uk as an alias. So I don't have a separate folder or .htaccess file for the .co.uk. I've also run out of virtual domains so I can't set it up just to do what you suggest (which is by far the best solution). 

In a sense, the server is doing exactly what it is supposed to, but I would like to over-ride it so that requests for the .co.uk were rewritten to be for the .com.

Any other ideas?

Thanks, 

Charlie

Comment: Oddly enough, this *only* doesn't work on Wordpress. I've had a look at a few of my flat html sites, and the same .htaccess configuration changes the domain even if you specify a particular page. Perhaps this is because Wordpress links are essentially folders rather than, say, file.html

Comment: Wordpress has its own redirects in place that you'd have to account for as well. It uses rewriting extensively.

Comment: Thank you. Still no joy, though. Left this out, perhaps it is relevant: this is the other part of the .htaccess file (and which isn't present in flat html sites) -

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

Essentially, each page in the Wordpress blog is like this: exampledomain.com/title/, whereas on my html sites it is exampledomain.com/title.html